# Any Alternative to ViewPager in android?

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to implement actionbar navigation via slide (Swiping the screen right or left). Came across ViewPager as a solution to it. But the issue is it is in support library and hence forces me to use fragments from support library. Is there any alternative to ViewPager to get same results?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry

Comment: whats wrong with fragments from support library? There is no solution afaik

Comment: TabActivity has been deprecated.

Comment: "But the issue is it is in support library and hence forces me to use fragments from support library" -- no, it does not. Use the `support-v13` library (not `support-v4`) and use the `support.v13` version of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and/or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Most of the projects in [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager) do so and work just fine.

Comment: If you only have static content, this is how you use view pager without fragments: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/